# multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops

I want to merge arrays based on index .how can I do this? following is my code

```
apple=["apple1","apple2"]
mango=["mango1","mango1"]
banana=["banana1","banana2"]
peach=["peach1","peach2"]
The expected output should be 
[{apple:"apple1",mango:"mango1",banana:"banana1",peach:"peach1"},
{apple:"apple2",mango:"mango2",banana:"banana2",peach:"peach2"}]
```

Comment: Could you post an example of some code that you've tried?

Comment: I tried with map function and do not use with multiple arrays

Comment: how can i use map function for this?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to map...

{string}{int} into a list?

If {int} is 0-9, then you can just take the last index of the string and order that.

If {int} is greater than possibly 0-9, I'd write a parser and parse the entire string and then check

if keyCode >= 48 || keyCode <= 57
intValue += keyCode

then at the end of the loop:

parseInt(intValue) and order based on that.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alpharithms.com%2Fascii-table-512119%2F&psig=AOvVaw0FueiAx4iB4JmxQiDzKNkz&ust=1666369404382000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCODo0vSb7_oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI

Answer (score 0):

I think, many new features from javascript, as per ex: ES6 can help you to achieve your result.

- Map & Set [From Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- A feu Logic with

  - loop `(for ... of)` style coupled with `Array/Object manipulation and Spread operator` can help you as well.
  - Using also the `built-in functions/prototypes from Array` like `filter & map` etc..